# Apply Monte Carlo simulation to historical data to determine probability of event to happen

Tags: r, monte-carlo

I have the data below and We have a game, that has a prize jackpot. The jackpot prize starts at 1,000 credits and every round you play the jackpot increases, until someone wins the jackpot and it resets back 1,000 credits.

To play a round you 'pay' 1 credit and the jackpot prize increases by 0.011382 (1.1383% of your 1 credit goes into the prize jackpot fund).

We have recorded the amounts the prize has been won at over the last few months.

The sample is small but we want to try to determine

Using the standard deviation or a monte carlo sim to see the chance of the prize going over 25,000 credits. How can I do this in R? I tried this but I do not know if im doing it right

```
prize_amounts <- c(
  3270.35, 3547.73, 3616.09, 4171.12, 2991.38, 4173.81, 1798.59, 7232.75, 5054.53,
  6476.27, 8259.84, 3932.46, 4346.68, 11433.26, 4850.1, 2905.25, 8174.9, 9307.45, 5737.27,
  4434.69, 7542.42, 8627.02, 7273.14, 9326.01, 9129.27, 7135.21, 3577.68, 10711.62,
  8933.94, 4224.24, 9283.57, 7467.65, 4977.56, 3526.48, 5248.06, 7831.2, 7333.13, 4839.57,
  8714.5, 8631.6, 1716.21, 5201.42, 7358.18, 9427.66, 1766.16, 9027.67, 5838.49, 6729.6,
  7872.61, 6003.57, 3389.34, 5542.54, 8265.95, 2364.84, 6586.25
)


# Monte Carlo Simulation
simulations <- 10000  # Number of simulations
target_amount <- 25000  # Target prize amount

results <- replicate(simulations, {
  jackpot <- 1000
  rounds <- 0
  
  while (jackpot < target_amount) {
    jackpot <- jackpot + 0.011382  # Increase jackpot by 1.1382%
    rounds <- rounds + 1
  }
  
  rounds
})

# Calculate the probability
probability <- mean(results <= 100)  # Assuming a round limit of 100
#probability <- sum(!is.na(results)) / simulations

cat("Probability of reaching 25,000 credits within 100 rounds:", probability)
```

Comment: A couple of comments based on my understanding of the problem: (i) I don't understand the use of `replicate()` as this function is expected to receive a formula or a data frame as first argument, not an integer; if you print the value of `results` in your implementation, you will see it's a constant-valued vector of length `simulations` (ii) I don't see you are using the `prize_amounts` data you have available... You could try to use it to estimate the probability of observing a given DELTA in the jackpot prize which would impact the prob. of reaching the prize of 25000 you want to estimate.

Comment: yes I agree especially with the 2nd comment but could you help with the solution?this is justa first chat gpt approach

Comment: if you skip my approach and keep only the data how would you approach the issue?

Comment: You need to figure out what it is that you're asking *in particular.*. What are you trying to predict?  What do you know about the generating process?

Comment: basically the probability of the prize to be over 25000.These are the prize amounts I have recorded the prize amount at when it has been won. 54 times it has been won.

Comment: What you should be modeling is the number of rounds between payouts. The probability of winning does not appear to be constant with jackpot size.

Comment: As for my point (ii), my suggestion would be to compute the delta(prize) values between two consecutive winning moments in `prize_amounts`, compute the empirical distribution of those values, and use this empirical distribution to sample a delta value at each time step of your simulation where the prize is won (and the probability of winning should be known or modeled in order to be used in the simulation) and make the prize won change by that sampled delta value.

Comment: @mastropi could u add this as an answer?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the need for a numerical approach here (Monte-Carlo). I would suggest the following modelling.

Let $N$ be the number of rounds played before the prize is won. It makes sense to assume $N$ has a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution): $N\sim\mathcal{Geo}(p)$.

On past data, we can estimate the probability $p$ of wining: $\hat{p}=1/(1+\frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=m}^{m}n_i)$ (
with $m$ sample size and $n_i$ computed number of rounds played: $n_i=\frac{Prize - 1000}{0.011382}$ )

Then using the CDF of $N$ we can compute the probability, that the prize exceeds 25000, i.e. $\frac{25000- 1000}{0.011382}$ rounds played without a win: $1-\mathrm{CDF}_N(\frac{25000- 1000}{0.011382})$

```
N<-(prize_amounts-1000)/0.011382
p<-1/(1+mean(N))
n_25<-(25000-1000)/0.011382
1-pgeom(n_25,p)
```

Comment: thank you but if you possibly wanted to do it with montecarlo how would u do it?

Answer (score 1):

As requested by the poster, I am adding my last comment above as an answer although it is just a suggestion and not a complete answer to the original question.

Considering the poster would like to run a simulation, although the requested probability can be estimated as described by Navzar, a possible way to run the simulation is to:

1. Compute the delta(prize) values between two consecutive winning moments given in `prize_amounts`
2. Compute the empirical distribution of those values
3. Use the empirical distribution to sample a delta value at each time step of the simulation where the prize is won. (This can be done using the inverse method on a uniformly distributed variable on (0,1).)
4. Make the prize won change by that sampled delta value.

For the simulation we also need to have an estimate of the winning probability, so that we can simulate that the prize is won. This could be done by the method described by Navzar.

Hope this helps.